# For which $a$, the DE $f'(x)=f(ax)$ has non- zero solution

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The question is

> > For which $a$, the differential equation $$f'(x)=f(ax)$$ has non- zero solution(s)?

Of course, for $a=1$, we have $f'(x)=f(x)$ which has the solution $f(x)=ce^{x}$.

For $a=-1$, the DE is $f'(x)=f(-x)$ which gives
$$f''(x)=-f'(-x)=-f(x)$$
and this gives $$f(x)=c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x$$
where from $f'(x)=f(-x)$, we see $f'(0)=f(0)$ and thus for $a=-1$, the solution is
$$f(x)=c_1(\cos x+\sin  x).$$
For $a\ne\pm1$, I have no idea how to proceed.

Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may did as for $f'(x)=f(-x)$ for general case $f'(x)=f(ax)$.

Note that from $f'(x)=f(ax)$ we have
    $$f''(x)=af'(ax)=af(a^2x),\quad f'''(x)=a^3f'(a^2x)=a^3f(a^4x), \ldots$$
    and in general
    $$f^{(n)}(x)=a^{n(n-1)/2}f(a^nx)$$
    which gives $$f^{(n)}(0)=a^{n(n-1)/2}f(0).$$
    Therefore the $f(x)$ is given by
    $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n=f(0)(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^{n(n-1)/2}}{n!}x^n)$$
    and by ratio test, we see that $$|a|\leq 1.$$

Comment: So, $f'(x)=f(2x)$ has only zero solution but $f'(2x)=f(x)$ has nonzero solution! A little weird to me

Comment: @Khayyam if it is weird to you, then the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n=\infty$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1/2)^n=0$ must be horrible! :)

Answer (score -2):

*Hint.* Let $y=f(x),\,w=ax,$ then we get $y'_x=y'_ww'_x=y(ax),$ which gives $$ay'=y,$$ where $y$ is now a function of $w.$ You should now be able to proceed.

Comment: Therefore $y(w)=e^{ w/a}$ or $f(x)=e^x$?

Comment: It is independent of $a$. But as I showed, for $a=\pm1$ we have different solutions

Comment: I am afraid that it is $ay'(w/a)=y(w)$.

Comment: @Allawonder: dear, $y=e^{aw}$ is not a solution.